# Unbold symbol in a bold environment or superscripts alignment

Tags: superscripts, boldmath, boldsymbol

I named a vector in such form

```
\overline{\pmb{\Delta S_{2}^{\star}}^{n}}^{x} = (\cdots)^T
```

resulting in

[image]

but \star and n were not aligned. So I wrote n with \star,

```
\overline{\pmb{\Delta S_{2}^{\star\,n}}}^{x} = (\cdots)^T
```

given

[image]

but n must be unbold. Is there any unbold command? Or any smart way to align superscripts in \overline{}? with \phantom{}?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should rather tell what symbols are to be made bold.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,bm}

\begin{document}

$\overline{\bm{\Delta}\bm{S}_{2}^{\bm{*}\,n}}^x$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Avoid `\pmb` as much as you can.